# How to put condition for Milestone so that it wont get removed from the related list of case?

Tags: apex, trigger, casemilestone, entitlements

I have a OOTB Milestone on an Entitlement Process which gets kicked when Status=New & SubStatus=Submit, so I have put the following conditions. I am using categoty & subcategory to differentiate my records.

When initially case gets created Status=New & SubStatus=New, Agent has to manually changed subStatus=Submit. But when the following conditions doesn't trigger the milestones why ?

**Case Milestone-1:**

```
Category=Paypal AND Subcategory=Basic Auth AND ((Status=New AND 
SubStatus=Submit) OR Closed=false) AND Is_Auth_req=Yes
```

Could you please how we can put the condition here ? So that when status & Substatus changes milestone should not get removed from an entitlement ?

Comment: what is milestones Recurrence Type?

Comment: First check, if the case has EntitlementId, then only you can track milestones

Comment: "how we can put the condition to allow not trigger SLA when status=new and SubStatus=Submitted"? question is no clear, when you could trigger the milestone and when you dont want to trigger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to successfully put the condition in an entitlement process by doing some tweaking.

```
Category=Paypal AND Subcategory=Basic Auth 
AND ((Status=New AND SubStatus=Submit) OR (SubStatus NOT EQUAL TO NEW)) 
AND Is_Auth_req=Yes AND Closed = false
```

So, this doesn't matter of my status/substatus values are changing, still my milestones and running and when the expected condition matches I am completing the milestone. This works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, your `OR Closed=false` condition should be replaced with `AND Closed=false`

```
Category=Paypal AND Subcategory=Basic Auth 
AND ((Status=New AND SubStatus=Submit) AND Closed=false) 
AND Is_Auth_req=Yes
```

Because of `OR Close=false` condition it is always satisfying irrespective of `status` and `SubStatus`

Comment: basically, it is not closing properly, thats why it is getting removed. I mean milestone completion date is not updated in that milestone